# Why every processing slots in Flink 1.4 use separate core?

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink

I have a docker-compose with hadoop [big-data-europe](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) and flink 1.10 and 1.4 which I try to start in separate container. I use this reference [YARN Setup](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html), in which there is an example

Example: Issue the following command to allocate 10 Task Managers, with 8 GB of memory and 32 processing slots each:

```
./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 10 -tm 8192 -s 32
```

When I use the flink 1.10 version, Flink cluster with yarn session starting is OK, but when version is 1.4 I get an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't deploy Yarn session cluster
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deploySessionCluster(AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.java:372)
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.run(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:679)
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli$1.call(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:514)
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli$1.call(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:511)
flinkmanger        |    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
flinkmanger        |    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.main(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:511)
flinkmanger        | Caused by: org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException: The number of virtual cores per node were configured with 32 but Yarn only has 8 virtual cores available. Please note that the number of virtual cores is set to the number of task slots by default unless configured in the Flink config with 'yarn.containers.vcores.'
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.isReadyForDeployment(AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.java:265)
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deployInternal(AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.java:415)
flinkmanger        |    at org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deploySessionCluster(AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.java:367)
flinkmanger        |    ... 8 more
```

How to explain this, I thought that every slot = thread (-s), and every task manager = yarn container, and only container can work on separate processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation for configuration parameters in yarn deployment mode](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#yarn), `yarn.containers.vcores` specifies the number of virtual cores (vcores) per YARN container. By default, the number of vcores is set to the number of slots per TaskManager, if set, or to 1, otherwise. In order for this parameter to be used your cluster must have CPU scheduling enabled.

In your case, you specify the `-s 32` `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots` parameter without overriding the `yarn.containers.vcores` setting thus the app acquires the container with 32 vcores. In order to be able to run with 32 slots per TM and only 8 cores, please, set the `yarn.containers.vcores` to `8` in `flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml`.

Regarding the resources, yes, every task manager equals to yarn container acquired, but container has a number of vcores, specified by `yarn.containers.vcores` (or to a number of slots per container). Regarding the slot, it's more like a resource group and each slot can have multiple tasks, each running in a separate thread. So, slot itself is not limited to only one thread. Please, find more at [Task Slots and Resources Docs page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#yarn).